# Gitlab Pipeline to build docker Image of dotnetcore application and deploy

Tags: docker, .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I have Installed Gitlab in one of the Ubuntu machine. And I have dotnetcore project in the name of ABC in the Gitlab.

But, In that ABC repo have multiple small doetnetcore application with different different directory like abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4.

I want to write a single pipeline under ABC to create the docker Image whenever developer push the code in the respective directory. but that need to be create docker Image for that only directory.

eg: Developer push the code under abc3 directory, that time pipeline run and create the docker Image for only abc3 directory.

Please help me out with it.
Thanks in Advance...!!!

Below is my pipeline what I have written also Docker file:

```
stages:
  - docker
  - build
  
services:
  - docker:dind
  
before_script:
    - "echo $gitlab"

docker-job:
  stage: docker
  image: docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u username -p password $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t dotnetcore .
    #- docker push $IMAGE_PUSH:latest
build:
  stage: build
  tags: 
    - shell
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk
  script:
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet build


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dotnetcore.csproj","./"]
RUN dotnet restore "dotnetcore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "dotnetcore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "dotnetcore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetcore.dll"]
```

In this pipeline and dockerfile I am only able to build "dotnetcore" project. But I have dotnetcore1 doctnetcore2 dotnetcore3 projects under the same Repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gitlab ci has a [only:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges) feature. You can define multiple jobs, each for one docker.

```yaml
job-a:
  script: docker build a
  only:
    changes:
      - a/**/*
job-b:
  script: docker build b
  only:
    changes:
      - b/**/*
```

Comment: Please share the complete pipeline example if you can..

Comment: not possible without seeing your current.

Comment: I have added the pipeline and dockerfile which I have written also, Just assume that, I have a git repo in the name of dotnetcore and inside of the dotnetcore repo I have multiple projects in the name of dotnetcore1 dotnetcore2 dotnetcore3.

Comment: your posted gitlab ci doesn't contain command to build one particular project, instead, seems a template of vs template. you should at least have jobs to build the 3 projects. then to learn how to trigger only when changed.

Comment: Thanks Lei Yang, I was not completely clear with your answer but get the clearly how that works. But few things not properly work but hope so that I will resolve soon

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a small number of directories. You can create a job for each directory. Use [rules with changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) to check if changes were made in the particular directory.

Comment: Yes,  but I want only once pipeline for all the subdirectory. I don't want multiple pipeline for each directory.